# SilverStripe ModelAdmin searchableFields function to map the fields with main text search box at the top

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. In my project, I am creating a ModelAdmin class to display the custom DataObject. I am also customizing the search/ filter fields by overriding the searchableFields function of the DataObject.

This is my simple searchableFields function of my DataObject class called Item.

```
public function searchableFields()
{
    return [
        'Title' => [
            'filter' => 'PartialMatchFilter',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'field' => TextField::class,
        ],
    ];
}
```

I can see the field in the filter form as in the screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see in the code, the title field will be mapped to the Title column of the Item data object in the database. But I also want to do some more customization on the search. As you can see, there is a big long search box above the filter form. For example, I want to configure that main search box to search through the Title column. Maybe other columns too. Maybe ID and Title columns. How can I configure that?